How can I switch between languages during runtime?
I'm getting errors trying to switch language of the Vuetify. Following this guide to set locale but useLocale function throws

Error: [Vuetify] Could not find injected locale instance

Here my attempt in Vuetify Playground. Getting the same error:
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-btn text="Change Language" @click="switchLanguage" />
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { useLocale } from 'vuetify'

  function switchLanguage() {
    const locale = useLocale()
    locale.current.value = locale.current.value === 'en' ? 'tr' : 'en'
  }
</script>


You have to run useLocale() during setup (in your example, you run it on click):
<script setup>
  import { useLocale } from 'vuetify'

  const locale = useLocale()

  function switchLanguage() {
    locale.current.value = 'tr'
  }
</script>

Here is the updated playground.

Thanks, that was the issue. Can you explain why does it require to be run during setup and not in function? Documentation would be great.

That's great! Under the hood, useLocale() uses injection, which only works during setup (afaik).
